# Empty Array in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a bit of a brute force workaround for a bug in my program, because there doesn't seem to be a way to refresh values assigned in the editor. Anyway, I'm trying to load images (sprites) into an array that another script can then use. However, it doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why. I've not done stuff like this before so I probably made a simple mistake. The error is saying pics1[i] is out of range. Here is my code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Imageblock : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite[] pics1;
public static Sprite[,] allPics;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    pics1 = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Dock Pics");
    allPics = new Sprite[100,100];
    for (int i = 0; pics1 [i] != null; i++) {
        allPics [1,i] = pics1 [i];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem with "refreshing values in the inspector"? Public fields will be serialized and therefore will be initialized by the inspector and also will be overridden by the inspector if you change them from there, but still it's possible to override them from code at runtime.

Comment: I have multiple instances of the same code so I need it to pull data from the inspector in the code, not on initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you for-loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pics1.Length; i++)
```

That might already do the trick. If you check pics1[900] it will not return null, but it will throw the IndexOutOfRangeException, that is why you want to check for existing indices beforehand. Of course within the valid range pic1[i] may return null, if the index is defined, but no element was assigned.

Comment: That did work! Thank you! Though now, I'm getting an error when trying to do things with the array.

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
(wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object)
icontap.Update () (at Assets/icontap.cs:38) is the error.

Comment: It refers to this: for (int i = 0; i < Imageblock.allPics.GetLength(1) != null; i++) {
    keyPics [i] = Imageblock.allPics[locationIdentifyer,i];
   }

Comment: Looks like the same mistake, change to: for(int i = 0; i < Imageblock.allPics.Length; i++). Or for lists, use the Count property.

Comment: I forgot to remove the != null, but it still doesn't work. allPics is multidimensional so I have to use Get.Length(1) to get the correct size of the array. It's quite odd, actually, because i have a Debug.Log right after it that is just supposed to output the value if i and its not.